# STM32F103x_XL FLASH bank 2 stays BUSY

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, stm32, flash-memory

I am using an STM32F103ZG with the STM32F10x_StdPeriph Library. I started the development of the project with Keil ARM-MDK but now moved over to GCC.
The switch over has gone pretty smooth until now. I use the last page of FLASH as a configuration page to store product specific parameters. This is page is obviously situated in bank 2. In certain instances these configuration parameters need to be updated at runtime, but now that I have moved over to GCC, the second memory bank goes into a busy state as soon as I try to write to it and then it stays busy until I cycle the power. Erase works fine, but writing fails.
I do unlock all the FLASH and make sure that all the clocks are initialized to access the FLASH. Some other posts on several forums suggest a problem with my linker file, but all the examples I use make no difference.

If anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong I will be very grateful.

Thanks,

H

```
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x800;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x800; /* required amount of stack */

MEMORY
{
 FLASH (rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
 FLASH_CFG (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x080FF800, LENGTH = 0x80
 RAM   (rwx)     : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x18000
}


SECTIONS
{
.text :
{
  _stext = .;          /* Provide the name for the start of this section */

    CREATE_OBJECT_SYMBOLS
    KEEP(*(.vectors))

    *(.text)
  *(.text.*)

. = ALIGN(4);        /* Align the start of the rodata part */
    *(.rodata)
  *(.rodata.*)
*(.glue_7)
  *(.glue_7t)

    . = ALIGN(4);        /* Align the end of the section */
} > FLASH
  _etext = .;             /* Provide the name for the end of this section */



.data : AT (_etext)
{
    . = ALIGN(4);        /* Align the start of the section */
    _sdata = .;          /* Provide the name for the start of this section */

          *(.data)
          *(.data.*)

    . = ALIGN(4);        /* Align the start of the fastrun part */
    *(.fastrun)
            *(.fastrun.*)

          . = ALIGN(4);        /* Align the end of the section */
} > RAM
    _edata = .;             /* Provide the name for the end of this section */


.bss :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);        /* Align the start of the section */
    _sbss = .;           /* Provide the name for the start of this section */

    *(.bss)
            *(.bss.*)

    . = ALIGN(4);        /* Align the end of the section */
} > RAM
_ebss = .;              /* Provide the name for the end of this section */

   ._user_heap_stack :
   {
     . = ALIGN(4);
     . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
     . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
     . = ALIGN(4);
   } >RAM

  _estack = ORIGIN(RAM) + LENGTH(RAM);


   .static_cfg :
   {
       . = ALIGN(4);        
     *(.static_cfg)
       *(.static_cfg.*)

       . = ALIGN(4);       
   } > FLASH_CFG
    _estatic_cfg = .;            

_end = .;
   PROVIDE (end = .);

 }
```

Comment: What does `objdump` say about the compiled binary? What are the sections, their addresses, sizes, attributes?

Comment: I think you should post the code you're using to program the flash.  Also, was this code working in Keil and is now not working in GCC, or is this some new code that wasn't in the code base when you were using Keil?

Comment: The code is exactly the same as used on Keil. Simply rebuilt it in GCC. I kept the compiler and linker options the same (as far as were possible as Keil has some specific options not available in GCC). The code simply calls the Unlock, Erase, Read and Write functions as per the STM32 Peripheral library supplied by ST.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to solve my problem.
When I moved over to GCC, I obviously had to recompile the STM32F10x Peripheral library and I lef the optimization setting to -O3. This was not allowed initially as the __STREXH and __STREXL core functions needed to be changed in order to build for the selected optimization. I found the following solution on a forum:

change __ASM volatile ("strexh %0, %2, [%1]" : "=r" (result) : "r" (addr), "r" (value) ); to
__ASM volatile ("strexh %0, %2, [%1]" : "=&r" (result) : "r" (addr), "r" (value) );

Several comments related to this solution specified that this solution does not cause any errors.

When I use the original code and set the optimization to -O0, everything works just fine. The access to the on-chip FLASH interface is 16bit and therefore if you screw up the above mentioned functions, all 16bit write accesses will be screwed up.

As I don't need optimization at this stage, I will stay without it.

Any suggestions about how to update these functions correctly for use with optimization will be appreciated.

Enjoy,

H